# UV Unwrapping Problem !

Tags: uv

I'm dying here with UV Unwrapping. I saw many tutorials many books about unwrapping UVs.I aslo search many software for easily unwrapping. In maya- uv unwrapping is so difficult. I came to Blender. Here its seems easy to unwrap but Still failed. I'm really confused about it.

Please give me some tips/suggestion about uv unwrapping (for any objects). Please Save me !

Comment: This question is currently too broad, if you are having a specific problem please add some screenshots or a blend file of that specific problem.

Comment: If you've watched all of the tutorials and read all of the books and articles out there and still can't get your models to unwrap the way you want, then it's unlikely that someone at random from this site is going to offer a tip that solves your issues.  I suggest you either phrase your problem in very specific terms, supplying screen captures and example blend files or you talk to a professional at Siggraph, or Full Sail or Pixar.  In other words, if you've done everything you can, seek a higher power.

Comment: A better way to make use of this site is by posting concrete examples of your problem: "I want this but I'm getting that", "I have this particular problem, what tool can I use to solve it?" Pictures, drawings, blend files or any other information to clarify your issue is not only welcome, but it's also the fastest way to get satisfactory answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific. UV-unwrapping is not something that you do in one single way and it's done. It could be done in many different ways and NO 2 objects are unwrapped the same way.

It depends on the object shape, topology of the mesh, texture you want to apply, places that would be visible and places that wont...

In General, you would look at the shape of the object, if it is somewhat spherical you will go for a spherical unwrapping technique, if it is somewhat cylindrical, then you would go for a cylindrical. If it has flat parts, you would extract it with a planar projection. Now, those are just basics, they wont give you perfect results, you then need to tweak UV's manually, use transformations, cuts and patches, and you would have to do tweaking as with everything artistic. UV unwrapping is an art in it's own right, you cannot expect to learn it in a day.

Like everything, the more you do it, the better you will become.